Не могу посчитать среднее арифметическое нечетных чисел в массиве Python
Задание звучит примерно так:
Найдите среднее арифметическое всех нечетных чисел массива.
код выглядит так:
(в первой части кода принимаем значения для массива и заносим их в него, работает во всех заданиях без нареканий, а вот во второй части считает арифметическое неверно, выдает число либо 1.0, либо 2.0 независимо от того, какие числа в массиве)
n = int(input("size"))
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    arr.append(x)
def arf(arr):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for m in range(n):
        if m % 2 != 0:
            total += m
            count += 1
    return total/count
print(arf(arr))


Вот здесь:
for m in range(n):

вы работаете с индексами, а не со значениями в списке
Замените на
for m in arf:

При применении вашего цикла внутри него нужно было бы arf[m] использовать
